# postgres window function with rank

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have some records which show users salary and department.
I'd like to know ranking and its diff.

```
SELECT depname, empno, salary, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC) FROM empsalary;
  depname  | empno | salary | rank 
-----------+-------+--------+------
 develop   |     8 |   6000 |    1
 develop   |    10 |   5200 |    2
 develop   |    11 |   5200 |    2
 develop   |     9 |   4500 |    4
 develop   |     7 |   4200 |    5
 personnel |     2 |   3900 |    1
 personnel |     5 |   3500 |    2
 sales     |     1 |   5000 |    1
 sales     |     4 |   4800 |    2
 sales     |     3 |   4800 |    2
```

I'd like to know the difference of each ranks salary

```
  depname  | empno | salary | rank | diff
-----------+-------+--------+------+------
 develop   |     8 |   6000 |    1 | 800
 develop   |    10 |   5200 |    2 | 700
 develop   |    11 |   5200 |    2 | 700
 develop   |     9 |   4500 |    4 | 300
 develop   |     7 |   4200 |    5 | 
 personnel |     2 |   3900 |    1 | 400
 personnel |     5 |   3500 |    2 | 
 sales     |     1 |   5000 |    1 | 200
 sales     |     4 |   4800 |    2 | 
 sales     |     3 |   4800 |    2 |
```

teach me the query which returns above.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `lag()`:

```
SELECT depname, empno, salary,
       rank() OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC) as rnk,
       (salary - lag(salary) over (partition by depname order by salary desc)) as diff
FROM empsalary;
```

EDIT:

I noticed that your data has duplicates -- hence the `rank()`.  This is a bit more troublesome, because Postgres does not support full the `range` keyword.  Here is one method that does not use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT depname, empno, salary, rnk,
       (salary - MIN(prev_salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname, rnk)) as diff
FROM (SELECT depname, empno, salary,
             rank() OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC) as rnk,
             lag(salary) over (partition by depname order by salary desc) as prev_salary
      FROM empsalary
     ) e;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT depname,empno, salary, rank() 
OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rnk, salary-lag(salary) 
OVER (partition BY depname ORDER BY  salary ) AS diff 
FROM empsalary ORDER BY depname, salary DESC;
```

Comment: hi try to answer to mo12mo34 question  ;-)

Comment: Please add some explanation to this so people can learn why it works

Comment: salary-lag(salary) gives difference on salary  by  depname

Comment: While this may answer the question, answers that only contain code without a description as to how the code work can be flagged as low quality. Consider adding a bit of text explaining the code that may help the OP and future visitors to this post. Also, that way, you are more likely to earn points on the question.